# ViewController fails to open with error "Attempt to present on ViewController0 which is already presenting"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For some reason, I keep getting the error "Attempt to present  on ViewController0 which is already presenting."

When I try to present a screen modally.
Here is the code where it calls a segue:

```
import UIKit

class WritingSimQuestionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var optlabelA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optlabelB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optlabelC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optlabelD: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var save: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var question: UITextView!
    
    var saveState = -1
    var actualquestionid = 0
    var control = 0
    
    var db: Firestore!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
       
        // Fill in the information
        getInfoAndSet()
        
        // Set Button Text if Saved
        if let writingValue = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "writingArray") as? [Int], writingValue.contains(actualquestionid) {
            self.save.setTitle("Click to Unsave", for: .normal)
            saveState = 1
        }
        else
        {
            self.save.setTitle("Click to Save", for: .normal)
            saveState = 0
            
        }
    }

    // 1 means saved, 0 means not saved.
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var arrayWriting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "writingArray") as! [Int]
        if saveState == 0 {
            arrayWriting.append(actualquestionid)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayWriting, forKey: "writingArray")
            /**let alert = UIAlertController(title: "SAT Daily", message: "Question is now saved. You can view your question in the Saved Library.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Thank you!", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true) **/
            self.save.setTitle("Click to Unsave", for: .normal)
            saveState = 1
        }
        else
        {
            if let index = arrayWriting.firstIndex(of: actualquestionid) {
                arrayWriting.remove(at: index)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayWriting, forKey: "writingArray")
                /**let alert = UIAlertController(title: "SAT Daily", message: "Question is now unsaved. You can no longer view your question in the Saved Library.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Thank you!", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)**/
                self.save.setTitle("Click to Save", for: .normal)
                saveState = 0
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func optionA(_ sender: Any) {
        let dailyToday = String(actualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                print(document.get("answer") as! String)
                if ((document.get("answer") as! String) == "optiona") {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCorrect", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    self.control = 1
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toIncorrect", sender: self)
                    self.control = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func optionB(_ sender: Any) {
        let dailyToday = String(actualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if ((document.get("answer") as! String) == "optionb") {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCorrect", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    self.control = 1
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toIncorrect", sender: self)
                    self.control = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func optionC(_ sender: Any) {
        let dailyToday = String(actualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if ((document.get("answer") as! String) == "optionc") {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCorrect", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    self.control = 1
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toIncorrect", sender: self)
                    self.control = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func optionD(_ sender: Any) {
        let dailyToday = String(actualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if ((document.get("answer") as! String) == "optiond") {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCorrect", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    self.control = 1
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toIncorrect", sender: self)
                    self.control = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    func getInfoAndSet()
    {
        
        let dailyToday = String(actualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
               // filler
                
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (control == 0)
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as! WritingCorrectSimViewController
            vc.actualactualquestionid = self.actualquestionid
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the area which should open but it does not:

```
import Firebase
import UIKit

class WritingCorrectSimViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var db: Firestore!
    var actualactualquestionid = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var congrats: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var explanation: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController
        {
            presented.removeFromParent()
        }
        
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        doStuff()
    }
    
    public func doStuff()
    {
        let dailyToday = String(actualactualquestionid)
        let docRef = db.collection("writing").document(dailyToday)
        docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                // Explanation Code
                let explanation = document.get("explanation")
                let explanationDisplay = explanation as! String
                self.explanation.text = explanationDisplay
            }
        }
        self.congrats.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1..<4)
        if randomInt == 1 {
            self.congrats.text = "Well done!"
        }
        else if randomInt == 2 {
            self.congrats.text = "Congrats!"
        }
        else if randomInt == 3 {
            self.congrats.text = "You are on a roll!"
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen is the first code I sent when the user gets the answer right modally opens a viewcontroller up. But instead, I get this error.
I tried looking at other threads but none of them seemed to solve my problem. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hello, did this answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your  are probably connecting the segue from the button rather than your viewController and then you call again `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: self)`, hence your are presenting the viewController twice.

1. Delete the segue you created from the button
2. add a new segue from the viewController as shown in the picture

this should solve your problem

[image]